# How to add night sky using Unity 5 procedural skybox?

Tags: unity-game-engine, skybox

I'm using Unity 5 and it's new procedural skybox. It looks amazing!

In my game, I have a day/night cycle. I can't find a way to use a night skybox which will slowly appear (blend) to replace the procedural skybox when the night comes.

I know a shader exists to blend between two skyboxes, but it won't work with the new procedural skybox.

I want to be able to keep the procedural skybox, so I can keep my amaizing sunrise/sunset, but be able to add stars at night.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't use `unity` tag for questions related to Unity game engine. It's generally a good idea to read the tags descriptions before using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use particles or use a sphere around the entire scene with stars textured all over it; use a transparent or particle shader on that material. :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new directional light, which the Unity will interpret as the sun. Then, just rotate it!

Comment: That's correct, but I assumed that the question was about the default procedural skybox in Unity 5.

Comment: Yeah I figured, would be interesting to know how to make a skybox compatible tough.

Comment: I haven't worked with Unity 5 skyboxes this much, but I don't think there's any way to be compatible with any sort of custom logic that the person who customises it would decide to implement.

Comment: I already know that, this is what i'm using, the default procedural skybox... but at night, its completely black.. I want to add stars to it. Like if I was using a normal skybox with 6 images.. I want to keep the procedural skybox but add stars to it at night.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a very big sphere around the player which isn't rendered but emitts small particels. You could turn it off at day time and fade it in by night.